# run built in commands in ABL language

Tags: command-line

For some reason in Ubuntu I cannot run built in commands in my code.

This same code works fine in other OS s.

input thru value("cd " + t-dir + " ; ls -1 last-*~"").

I get the /bin/bash: error, for some reason the code cannot find the "cd" command.

Probably my code.  I'm just putting out there while on work on the ABL code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a space in `"cd "`? Does it work if you use `input thru value("cd" + " " + t-dir)`?

Comment: have a space to simulate what i would type on the command line.  I got it to work last night, this is the syntax input thru value("cd " + t-dir + "; ls last-*~"").  thanks for replying.

Comment: If you got it t work, could you please post your solution as an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: the solution in under my comment. I took out the -1.

Comment: sorry, i did not take out the -1.  it was actually another input from that was causing me grief.    some reason the bash does not like the tilde                                               
           before:  /*input thru value("cat " + t-dir + tt-log.file-name +
                    " | $DLC/bin/quoter~""). */
            after:  input thru value("cat /usr/local/hb/last*" + " | $DLC/bin/quoter").

Comment: Great, but could you please post it as an answer? Otherwise the system won't see this as answered. Plus, you can accept it and get a bit of reputation which will let you do more things on the site if you decide to stick around!